# java.rmi.UnmarshalException: unable to pull client classes by server

Tags: java, rmi, unmarshalling, codebase

I have an RMI client/server set-up on two machines that works fine in a simple situation when the server doesn't require a client-side defned class.  However, when I need to use a class defined on the client side I am unable to have the server unmarshall those classes.  I suspect this is an issue with my `java.rmi.server.codebase` property that I pass in as argument to the client app.  I followed Sun's RMI Tutorial trail and I think I have followed the steps exactly except that I don't specify a classpath argument when executing client and server because they execute in the directory right above the root package directory (however I tried that too with no effect).

The exceptions I get when attempting to execute the different client-side combinations described in detail below are all the same:

`RmiServer exception:
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
 java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling arguments; nested exception is: 
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.MyTask
 at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:353)
 at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:177)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:173)
 at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:553)
 at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:808)
 at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:667)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
 at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:255)
 at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:233)
 at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:142)
 at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invokeRemoteMethod(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:178)
 at java.rmi.server.RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteObjectInvocationHandler.java:132)
 at $Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
 at test.myClient.main(myClient.java:32)`

The details are:

My client/server rmi is set up over a home network behind a router.  The router is assigned to a static ip address I will call `myhostname`.  Appropriate port-mapping is set-up in the router that points to the right machines.

**role, machine, os, ip-address:**

`server, venice, linux ubuntu 9.10, 10.0.1.2` 
`client, naples, mac os x leopard, 10.0.1.4`

I startup the server side as follows inside `/home/andrews/workspace/epsilon/bin`:

1 starting registry on the default port 1099:

`venice% rmiregistry &`

2 starting web-server on port 2001 pointing to code base for common interfaces:

`venice% java webserver/ClassFileServer 2001 /home/andrew/workspace/epsilon/bin`

3 starting server app (main class in test/myServer) which registers the server object:

`venice% java -Djava.rmi.server.codebase="http://myhostname:2001/" -Djava.security.policy=server.policy -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=myhostname test/myServer &`

Now the client side inside `/Users/andrews/Development/Java/workspace/epsilon/bin`:

1 start a local web server that can server client-side classes to the server (not sure if this is needed, but I added I tried it, and still no success; I have added port-mapping to the router for 2001 to `venice`, for 2002 to `naples`)

`naples$ java webserver/ClassFileServer 2002 /Users/andrews/Development/Java/workspace/epsilon/bin/`

Trying to run the client (note: I don't specify the `-cp` argument because client executes right above the root package directory):

1 try #1 using an http hostname

`naples$ java -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=http://10.0.1.4:2002/ -Djava.security.policy=client.policy test.myClient myhostname`

Note 1: the `myhostname` argument at the end is passed-in to the client so that it resolves to server's rmi hostname.

Note 2: I tried using `localhost:2002` instead of `10.0.1.4:2002` too.

Note 3: I tried using `myhostname:2002` since `myhostname` is assigned to the router and I have proper port-mapping set-up, this address should resolve to `naples` and not `venice`

2 try #2:

`naples$ java -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/Users/andrews/Development/Java/workspace/epsilon/bin/ -Djava.security.policy=client.policy test.myClient myhostname`

Note 1: the code base url format is correct, I created a small program to convert current file directory path into a url and used that.  using `file:///Users...` has same effect.

Other notes:

1 my server and client policy files correctly specify the path, as I've tested this setup with good and bad paths, and getting a security exception for bad path

2 this setup works if I don't use client-side defined objects, the client connects correctly to the server and the server executes.

3 when I place the client-side class on the server in the server's classpath, all executes fine.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: I tried bundling the client classes into a jar file, but that doesn't work either:

`naples$ java -Djava.rmi.server.codebase=file:/Users/andrews/Development/Java/workspace/epsilon/bin/client.jar -Djava.security.policy=client.policy test.myRmi myhostname'

Also, I switched roles of the two machines but the results are the same.

Comment: My set-up works if I use the mac as the server and ubuntu as the client, but only when both are running web servers that reference respective code bases and I use the http address as codebases.  So this must be a mac os network permissions issue I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use RMI? Me and a friend tried it once in school and it was **way** slow, much slower then the simple ObjectOutputStream networking we had been doing earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I strong agree with Chad Okere's said, RMI is really very slow and consuming-resouces. sometimes directly use Sockets maybe is simple and useful chooice, regarding your exception Could you confirm your rmi server work correctly? http://www.javarmi.com/2010/05/java-rmi-error-unmarshalling-arguments/ maybe be can help you